# C++ Error linking in consumer file caused by static data field

Tags: c++, static, mutex, static-members, static-variables

I want to use a static global variable as a mutex. When I try to compile the following code:

```
//header file

class __declspec(dllexport) StateConservator
{
private:
    StateConservator();
    StateConservator(const StateConservator&);

protected:
    const CString m_oldConf;
    CContainer& m_container;
    static bool x_mutex;
public:
    StateConservator(CContainer& container, const CString& conf)
        : m_container(container)
        , m_oldConf(!x_mutex? container.GetConf():_T(""))
    {
        if(!x_mutex)
        {
            x_mutex= true;
            m_container.SetConf(conf);
        }
    }

    ~StateConservator()
    {
        if(x_mutex)
        {
            x_mutex= false;
            m_container.SetConf(m_oldConf);
        }
    }
};


//cpp file
bool StateConservator::x_mutex= false;


//consumer file
StateConservator cs(*pContainer, pDoc->GetConfiguration());
```

I get the error:

`Consumer.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: static bool StateConservator::x_mutex" (?x_mutex@StateConservator@@1_NA)`

Please, how can I solve the problem?

**UPDATE**

I created two minimal programs containing only the essential part to test the problem and they work! This is getting even more strange!

**UPDATE 2**

Notice the **__declspec(dllexport)** declaration after the class, that was missing.

Comment: Since it's a linker error and not a compiler error, are you sure both files are compiled with the same settings? I assume you're using Visual C++, but is this in a single project in Visual Studio or do they span projects?

Comment: @AustinMullins: I verified that, and yes they have the same settings.

Comment: Try doing a clean build.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee: I tried. The problem continues to exist.

Comment: Is your .cpp file actually getting compiled and linked in your project?

Comment: Oh, and bools are not mutexes. You need to use an actual mutex. You will have race conditions.

Comment: What is an actual mutex, @RobK?

Comment: [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) is. Or, if your compiler doesn't offer C++11, you can use an object created with [CreateMutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, people.

I was defining the code of StateConservator in a file belonging to the project. But after I realized it would make more sense in another file.

I was not realizing the second file was part of another solution. So, I did not compile the second solution, hence the error.

I think I need an extension to Visual Studio to colorize the tabs of other projects with another color. If somebody knows about one, I will appreciate.

Thanks for supporting the annoyance caused by me.

**UPDATE**

Notice the **__declspec(dllexport)** declaration after the class, that was missing.